# How to Get The Count or The Number Of Rows In A Result Set In PHP using ODBC Connection?

Tags: php, sql, odbc, count, sybase

While I build a web page in My PHP web application, My Connection works ok but When I want to get the count of rows of the SELECT Statement I used in my query, It gives me -1 !! although my result set has about 10 rows.

I would like to get the actual number of result set rows.
I searched the PHP Manual & documentation but I do not find a direct way like a Count function or something like that.

I wonder if I have to make a Count(*) SQL Statement in another query and attach it to my Connection to get the Count of Rows ?

Does any one knows an easy and direct way to get that ?

the odbc_num_rows function always gives -1 in result so I can not get the actual number of rows.

My Programming langauge is PHP and My Database Engine is Sybase and The Way to connect to Database is ODBC.

Here are you the Code I used:-

```
<?PHP

//PHP Code to connect to a certain database using ODBC and getting information from it

//Determining The Database Connection Parameters
$database = 'DatabaseName';
$username = 'UserName';
$password = 'Password';

//Opening the Connection
$conn = odbc_connect($database,$username,$password);

//Checking The Connection
if (!$conn)
{
exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

//Preparing The Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1='$v_Field1'";

//Executing The Query
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

//Checking The Result Set
if (!$rs)
{
exit("Error in SQL");
}

echo "<p align='Center'><h1>The Results</h1></p>";

while ( odbc_fetch_row($rs) )

{
  $field1 = odbc_result($rs,1);
  $field2 = odbc_result($rs,2);
  $field3 = odbc_result($rs,3);
  echo "field1 : " . $field1 ;
  echo "field2 : " . $field2 ;
  echo "field3 : " . $field3 ;
}

$RowNumber = odbc_num_rows($rs);

echo "The Number of Selected Rows = " . $RowsNumber ; 

//Closing The Connection
odbc_close($conn);

?>
```

Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: Thank you but I tried that too and it give me -1 as The PHP Manual said but this makes this function without practical application and use. there may be another function or simple way to do that. I hope anyone who did examples like that before to answer me. Thanks in advance. I do not want a working around way like making two queries with the same connection as my basic query is not simple and has no table name. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`odbc_num_rows` seems to be reliable for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE queries only.

The [manual](http://www.php.net/odbc_num_rows) says:

> Using odbc_num_rows() to determine the number of rows available after a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers.

one way around this behaviour is to do a `COUNT(*)` in SQL instead. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-num-rows.php#98836) for an example.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Pekka , I read that when i checked The Manual and My question is How to get the Count Directly without working around. There may be another way that is commonly used.

Comment: Thanks for Help although Neither of these answers solved my question but I make another solution by making two result sets, one to store my results and the other to store the count or the number of rows and it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

in php.net:

The easy way to count the rows in an odbc resultset where the driver returns -1 is to let SQL do the work:

```
<?php

    $conn = odbc_connect("dsn", "", "");
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Count(*) AS counter FROM tablename WHERE fieldname='" . $value . "'");
    $arr = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
    echo $arr['counter'];

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

On what basis, do you expect `odbc_num_rows` to return anything other than -1 ?

We have the fact from the manuals, that OBDC does not support `@@ROWCOUNT / odbc_num_rows`.  So there is no basis for expecting that it "should" return anything other than that which is documented, -1 in all circumstances.

Even if you used Sybase directly (instead of via ODBC), you would have the same "problem".

- `odbc_num_rows` returns `@@ROWCOUNT`, which is the rows inserted/updated/deleted by the immediately preceding command.  -1 is the correct, documented value, if the immediately preceding command is *not* insert/update/delete.
- It has nothing to do with ***rows in a table***.

Use another batch, and either one of the *documented* methods to obtain *rows in a table*, and load the value into a variable:

- SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) -- slow, requires I/O
  or
- SELECT @Count = ROW_COUNT(db_id, object_id) -- very fast, no I/O

Then interrogate the result array, to obtain the variable, not `odbc_num_rows`, which will continue returning -1.