# Format any resultset to JSON using ODBC

Tags: c, odbc

I am working on a client interface that can connect to any DB by passing the desired query in an input field and the server side (coded in C and using sql.h), parses this query and returns content in JSON format. I am able to accomplish this easily by using  Select * from tablename query as i am able to get the number of rows using the count(*) query and i use this with a for loop to print my JSON into a buffer. How am i to accomplish the same for anyother query?

I read up somewhere that row-wise binding might help but whats the logic behind parsing a resultset into a json format? (under the assumption that i need the data in a row-wise format. example : `{"Records" : [["col heading 1", "col heading 2", "col heading 3"], ["row content 1", "row content 2", "row content 3"]...]}`)

Comment: Any reason for wanting to write the server side in C? Of course it can be done but given better tools for this job available today I cannot see why are you inflicting yourself that pain... Such a server written with any of the web framework tools is just a few lines of code.

Comment: "Implementing ODBC"? There's implemented ODBC C lib. You could just wrap it and add the functionality, you need. Or I am missing something?

Comment: There ya go @Kiril. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODBC only offers a way (`SQLRowCount`) to find out the number of affected rows for `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / `INSERT` Statements - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711835%28v=VS.85%29.aspx...

IF you want to find out the number of rows of a `SELECT` you either execute the query a second time as `SELECT COUNT(*)` OR you just loop over the result set and count the rows ODBC delivers...

see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/6fe5403d-900c-4b07-9d00-1f42731b5602
and [How to Get The Count or The Number Of Rows In A Result Set In PHP using ODBC Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117351/how-to-get-the-count-or-the-number-of-rows-in-a-result-set-in-php-using-odbc-conn/4117354#4117354)

*NOTE: Although the second link mentions PHP, the answer is language-agnostic since the cause of the behaviour lies in the ODBC standard and the used ODBC driver.*