# how to call sybase view using odbc in PHP

Tags: php, odbc, sybase

I am trying to fetch the records from the **sybase** view **ODBC** in PHP but it does not return data. 
I am getting records from table but not able to get data from view.

`Query -- select * from odb.VP_myview;`

`odb = odbc DSN
VP_myview = view`

Above query does not show any error but same time it does not return any records.

Below is PHP code

```
<?php
$con = @odbc_connect('DSN','USERNAME','PASSWORD',SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC) or die("<B>Error!</B> Couldn't Connect To Database. Error Code:  ".odbc_error());
$query = 'select * from odb.VP_myview';
$result = odbc_exec($con,$query);
$totrec = odbc_num_rows($result);
var_dump($totrec);// it return negative integer number
exit;

?>
```

It would be really great help. I am trying since last 3-4 days but no success.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> Using odbc_num_rows() to determine the number of rows available after
>   a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers.

That's especially true for Sybase. C.f. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117351/how-to-get-the-count-or-the-number-of-rows-in-a-result-set-in-php-using-odbc-con)